# python measure distance by NM

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I'm using the Folium Leaflet library and I want to incorporate a measurement tool that calculates distances in Nautical miles. I attempted to use the Measure Control plugin from Folium, but it only provides distances in Miles, and I encountered an issue where the tool doesn't function properly when marking the first point—it moves offsite. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on this matter.

Additionally, I would like to know if it's possible to replace the Folium map with another offline option. I have been trying various approaches for the past two weeks but haven't found a solution yet. I hope you can assist me with this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions that ask for software/library recommendations are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site because any answer is generally just an opinion.. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.